# Relation between coefficients of Maclaurin series and recurrence relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $I_{2n}=\int_0^{\pi}x\sin^{2n}x \;dx$. Then one can obtain the following:
$$I_0= \frac{\pi ^2}{2}, I_1= \frac{\pi ^2}{4}, I_2= \frac{3\pi ^2}{16}, I_3= \frac{5\pi ^2}{32},\ldots, I_n= \frac{{2n\choose n}\pi ^2}{2^{2n+1}}.   $$

Note that the Maclurin series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is

$$1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}+\frac{5x^3}{16}+\ldots + \frac{(-1)^n{2n \choose n}x^n}{2^{2n}}+\ldots.$$

This means thatthe Maclurin series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is 
$$\frac{2}{\pi ^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_nx^n$$

Is there any relationship, in general, for other recurrence relation and coefficients of Maclaurin series? If yes, what is that?

Comment: Differential equations translate to recurrence relations using $D x^n = n x^{n-1}$.  That is a standard technique.

Answer (score 0):

For a general discussion of recurrences and series take a look at Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).